# Is it better to use `$this` or to avoid it when calling another method in the same PHP class?

Tags: php, oop

When calling a method in the same class from within another method, is it better to use `$this` or to avoid it, or is there no difference at all?

One benefit I can see with using `$this` is that it is explicit. For example:

```
class A {
  public function a() {
    $x = $this->b();// or $x = b()
  }

  public function b() {
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried `$x = b()`, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: You have two ways. `self::methodName()` and `$this->methodName()`.

Comment: As @GrasDouble said it will not work without `$this`. If you actually execute your code without `$this` you'll receive:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function b() in /yourpath/yourfile.php on line n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other languages, like `C++` and `C#` and `Java`, to access a member property of a class in `PHP`, you must always use `$this` as a qualifier upon the property.

For example:

```
class Test {
    public $myVariable;

    public function __construct($a) {
        $this->myVariable = $a;
        // $myVariable doesn't exist, must always use $this-><*>
    }
}
```